# How can I make Drake do a kung-fu disarm?

Tags: uncharted-3

Once in a while, when I melee an enemy soldier, Drake pulls off a piece of kung-fu action and kills the enemy while whisking away his gun (for example, in one, Drake kicks a shotgun out of an opponent's hands and then grabs it as it falls down).  In another, Drake pulls the pin from a grenade that an opponent is holding and then kicks them away, so that the grenade kills them a few seconds later.

Frankly, I think all these animations are pretty cool to watch, and I'd like them to happen all the time.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure what conditions are required to get them to trigger.

**Are kung-fu disarms random in Uncharted 3, or can I force them to occur?**

Comment: I think that you can force them. I didn't play it for over 8 months, so can't say for sure. I'll provide more info when I'm home and I can play a bit of Uncharted 3.

Comment: I think it only happens when you melee an enemy carrying a weapon of type you don't have (e.g you don't have a long gun and attack an enemy carrying one)

Comment: The grenade things is random as well but will only be on an enemy carrying a grenade, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that JohnoBoy's comment is partially correct.

**Drake will do a Kung-fu disarm whenever he successfully melee-kills an opponent who is carrying a weapon type that Drake has no ammo for, unless the melee kill is already a special animation (such as a bottle bash or stealth kill)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it only happens if Drake doesn't have a rifle type gun.  If he does, I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer is correct. Also, as he said you can initiate bottle bash techniques, as long as your environment supports it. This is also true for disarms. For example, if you have no handgun, and you knock a handgun enemy into a crouch cover, 9 times out of 10 Drake will break the enemy's arm while taking his weapon. It's kind gross looking, but it's the best example I could think of off the top of my head. :)